# Running sum of the last n integers in an array

Tags: c, algorithm

Let's suppose that a process receives a new integer every 60 seconds.  I would like to keep a running total of the last 5 numbers.  For example:

```
3 1 99 10 8 0 7 9 --> running total is 10+8+0+7+9==34
       <--------->
```

Sixty seconds later, we receive a new integer.  The list of received integers now looks like this:

```
3 1 99 10 8 0 7 9 2 --> running total is now 8+0+7+9+2==26
          <-------->
```

It's easy to implement this if you have storage space to save the last 5 integers.  I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that's more memory efficient than that.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You're so hurting for memory, 20 bytes is too much (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`)?

Comment: This seems more like a programming puzzle than a practical programming question. Maybe you should post it at codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So, is your code size budget 19 bytes to get an overall memory reduction? Could you shave that off something else instead, or is variable storage at a premium?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you can't do that. If you could store the sum of the last n numbers in less than O(n) memory for arbitrary data, that would imply you can store n arbitrary numbers in less than O(n) memory, which is absurd.

Comment: I'm simplifying the problem for the sake of the discussion.  In practice, there will be 8000 or so such lists and I will need to keep the running sum of the last 5, 60, and 3600 elements.  That's why I'm so concerned about a memory-efficient solution.

Comment: If size is too much for you, I'd start looking for alternative solutions. Do you really need exact sum? How many bits do you really need per number? Would variable length encoding help? Would storing deltas help? Could you use some actual compression algorithm, would it save space or be fast enough? Etc.

Comment: Sorry... I was going to suggest deltas, but just spotted that @hyde already suggested this.

Comment: @Andy Definitely needs an update on accuracy.  I tend to use rolling averages for this type of thing, which would only take the sums for storage - they're not very accurate, but they're simple.  (That is, if `s5` is the sum of the last 5, and the next number is `x`, then `s5 - (s5 / 5) + x`) (The 99 in your example does throw it way off though, it's better when numbers are in the same general range)

Comment: @Andy An alternative approach is to use an exponential window moving average (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average). Basically the same as Izkata suggested, but IMO it is not a matter of "less accurate" but "different thing".

Comment: In theory, you can use less than `n` memory slots if you use compression - maybe bitwise run-length encoding or Huffman coding? But such startegies only minimize average memory use. Worst-case memory use, when the entropy of the numbers is high, will still require `n` memory slots.

Answer (score 22):

Since you can reconstruct the last n numbers, for example if you feed in n zeros, anything you do is equivalent to storing the last n numbers.

Assuming the numbers can be truly random and each number is b bits long, any correct algorithm can therefore exactly reproduce nb random bits. This requires at least nb bits of storage.

Comment: My comment above has equivalent conclusion. I can't formally prove it, but it seems to me you are right.

Comment: +1 for reasoning about the problem. It's always tempting to dive in and write code, but code is a distraction from thinking.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you can solve this problem as described.

For a running sum of the most two recent integers, you must store at least the very first integer and the current running sum, to reconstruct the second (or last) integer. This means storing two integers.

Given the first integer:

> a<sub>1</sub>

The running sums *s<sub>i,j</sub>* for the last two indices *i* and *j* can be calculated iteratively as integers *a<sub>2</sub>* and so on come into the stream, reusing the previous running sum:

> s<sub>1,2</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>
>
> s<sub>2,3</sub> = s<sub>1,2</sub> - a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>
>
> s<sub>3,4</sub> = s<sub>2,3</sub> - (s<sub>1,2</sub> - a<sub>1</sub>) + a<sub>4</sub>
>
> s<sub>4,5</sub> = s<sub>3,4</sub> - (s<sub>2,3</sub> - (s<sub>1,2</sub> - a<sub>1</sub>)) + a<sub>5</sub>
>
> ...

And so on, in recursive fashion.

As you can see, a running sum of two integers requires at least *a<sub>1</sub>* and the running sum *s<sub>i-2,i-1</sub>*, to reconstruct the next-to-last element.

Likewise, for a running sum of the most three recent integers, you must store at least the first two integers and the current running sum, to reconstruct the third (or next-to-last) integer.

Given the first and second integers:

> a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>

The running sums *s<sub>i,j,k</sub>* for the last three indices *i*, *j* and *k* can be calculated iteratively as integers *a<sub>3</sub>* and so forth come into the stream, reusing the previous running sum:

> s<sub>1,2,3</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>
>
> s<sub>2,3,4</sub> = s<sub>1,2,3</sub> - a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>4</sub>
>
> s<sub>3,4,5</sub> = s<sub>2,3,4</sub> - a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>5</sub>
>
> s<sub>4,5,6</sub> = s<sub>3,4,5</sub> - (s<sub>1,2,3</sub> - a<sub>1</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>) + a<sub>5</sub>
>
> ...

Again, you must store as many integers for the running sum as required to reconstruct the missing integer. By induction, were you to eliminate any one variable, you would be unable to recapitulate the missing value.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that you have a function *f* that maps some set of integers *A* to another set *B* (*f:A->B*). Let's say the goal here is that the set of integers in *B* is summed up, generating the running sum, and the set *A* are those integers *a1*, *a2*, etc. that we want to store in our array. If the cardinality of set *A* is less than the cardinality of set *B*, then at least one number in *A* can map to one of two or more numbers in *B*. How do you pick either number in a repeatable fashion, *i.e.* in a computer program?

Answer (score 10):

> I'm simplifying the problem for the sake of the discussion. In
>   practice, there will be 8000 or so such lists and I will need to keep
>   the running sum of the last 5, 60, and 3600 elements.

Sounds like you want the total over the last 5 seconds, 60 seconds, and 1 hour.

Do you really need your 60-second total to be accurate to the second? Or would it be OK to update every 5 seconds? Similarly, do you need your hourly total to be accurate to the second, or would updating once a minute be OK?

If you don't need your per-minute and per-hour totals to be accurate to the second, then you can save a lot on storage. In this case 5 + 12 + 60 = **77, instead of 3600**.

The algorithm then runs like this:

```
//these are the running totals that will be displayed
int last1 = 0;    //updated every second
int last5 = 0;    //updated every second
int last60 = 0;   //updated every 5 seconds
int last3600 = 0; //updated every minute

// 3 circular buffers:
// last 5 1-second periods (updated every second)
int period1[5] = {0};
// last 12 5-second periods (updated every 5 seconds)
int period5[12] = {0};
// last 60 1-minute periods (updated every minute)
int period60[60] = {0};

//indexes for the circular buffers
int index1 = 0;
int index5 = 0;
int index60 = 0;
while (1) {
    printf("1s 5s 1m 1h\n");
    printf("%2d %2d %2d %2d\n", last1, last5, last60, last3600);

    sleep(1);
    last1 = getNewValue();

    //update last5 by subtracting the expiring period and adding the new one
    last5 -= period1[index1];
    last5 += last1;
    //and save the new period to circular buffer
    period1[index1] = last1;
    index1++;

    //if we get to the end of the circular buffer we must go to the start
    //we have also completed a 5s period so we can update last60
    if (index1 >= 5) {
        index1 = 0;

        //similar to before
        last60 -= period5[index5];
        last60 += last5;

        period5[index5] = last5;
        index5++

        //similar to above, but now we have completed a 60s period
        //so we can update last3600
        if (index5 >= 12) {
            index5 = 0;

            //similar to before
            last3600 -= period60[index60];
            last3600 += last60;

            period60[index60] = last60;
            index60++

            if (index60 >= 60) {
                index60 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, all up only 84 ints are required, and no looping is done so performance will be good.

If you want the 60-second total to be updated every second instead of every 5s, you can do this. You can also get more fiddly, e.g. have the 1 hour period be updated every 20 seconds. However, part of the reason the code is so neat is that each period is updated each time you finish one period below it.

Note that the 3600-second total is the one that uses the most memory so that's the one you need to be most careful about.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe you can do that. You need a sliding window able to hold that last `n` values.

About the best you can do is use modulo n arithmetic to treat an array as a  circular buffer, maintaining a running sum and count as you go so as to avoid having to iterate over the entire buffer to compute the sum of values. Something like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WINDOW_SIZE 5

static int   *window      ;
static int    i           ;
static double sum         ;
static double cnt         ;

double record_value( int value )
{
  double mean ;

  i          = (i+1) % WINDOW_SIZE ;
  sum        = sum - window[i] + value ;
  cnt       += cnt < WINDOW_SIZE ? 1 : 0 ;
  window[i]  = value ;

  mean = sum/cnt ;
  return mean ;
}

void log_message( double avg )
{
  int x = 0 ;

  printf( "%f = ( " , avg ) ;
  for ( int x = 0 ; x < cnt ; ++x )
  {
    printf( "%s%d" , x > 0 ? " + " : "" , window[x] ) ;
  }
  printf( " ) / %d\r\n" , (int)cnt ) ;
  return ;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int j ;

  window      = calloc( WINDOW_SIZE , sizeof(window[0]) ) ;
  i           = WINDOW_SIZE - 1 ;
  sum         = 0 ;
  cnt         = 0 ;

  for ( j = 0 ; j < 100 ; ++j )
  {
    int    v   = rand() ;
    double avg = record_value( v ) ;

    log_message( avg ) ;

  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: A circular buffer is an excellent idea. Not only is it efficient, but you don't need separate lists for calculating multiple lengths of sums - just do your subtractions from different spots in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If your input has some constraints, maybe there are hacky ways to go about this.

A `char` takes 1 byte. Given your input examples, if your integers are positive values and less than three digits long, *i.e.* between 0 and 99, then you could perhaps save some space by reducing your integers to a `char` stream split by delimiters.

Given the trailing sum of a stream of digits like this:

```
3 1 99 10 8 0 7 9
```

Perhaps this could be reduced to storing two elements: the last five elements as a constantly `realloc`-ed `char *` and the sum as an `int`:

```
"10|8|0|7|9" (10 bytes)
34 (4 bytes)
```

This requires a total of 14 bytes, 6 bytes less than the 20 bytes required for storing five `int` values.

You'd need to write code to tokenize and extract elements from the `char *` to recalculate the sum, and you'd `realloc` and rewrite the character buffer as new elements come in and the buffer's length changes, so that you are always maximizing the potential space savings.

Note also the lack of a NULL terminator on the `char *` — you would not want to treat this as a string, to maximize storage efficiency. A NULL is a wasted byte.

You'd also want a careful way to rewrite the `char *` so that you don't have to waste space on intermediate storage. For a very large `char *`, you might waste space on a four-byte `size_t` to note the offset of the true start of the stream, so that you don't waste time rewriting it, and a four-byte `size_t` value so that you know when you get to the end and need to wrap around (or you'd waste a byte on a NULL, and test for that).

A stream of five one- or two-digit integers with four delimiters and no NULL would require — at most — 16 bytes, and as few as 9 bytes. A cumulative sum stored as an `int` would take 4 bytes. Worst case scenario, you are using the same storage as five `int` variables. In the best case, you are using 13 bytes — seven less than the worst case.

Assuming not all your integers are two digits long, you *might* see some space savings. However, given a uniformly random stream of integers from 0 to 99, you'd expect 90 percent of those random numbers to be two digits long. So, on average, it is likely that this would use closer to 20 bytes, most of the time.

If you really want to be a cheapskate, store the cumulative sum as a three-byte `char *`. The maximum sum (given the same constraints) will be 99 + 99 + 99 + 99 + 99 = 495. The value `"495"` can be stored in three bytes. So that's an extra byte of savings.

Note that this does not take into consideration the operating system's word length and other optimizations that might pad data structures, etc. So this very simple and restricted example may not even really save as much space as intended, in the end.

If you are dealing with very large streams, consider a similar approach that would use block-level compression algorithms, like bzip2 or gzip. Depending on the scale of your data, you might gain more storage savings than what you lose from compression overhead. You probably want to avoid encoding schemes that require extracting the entire stream to recover just the first integer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get to fewer than 5 variables stored if you have to continuously iterate through new values. If all your integers are small it might make sense to store all 5 values in a more appropriate type (a char), which will use less space than an int.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a cs-style reduction.

I'm going to assume your question to be possible, and show that we can create a lossless compression algorithm which has an output always shorter than the input.

**Compression algorithm(compresses in 5-byte chunks):**
Add the 5 bytes together, store in new 11-bit integer. We can use 2 wholes bytes for this I guess. It's still compression.

**Decompression algorithm(takes 2-bytes, returns 5-bytes):**
Call our running total, the 2-byte number.

Add a 0 to the "list" (quoted because there is no list. We only have our running total). Compare the new running total with the old one. The difference is the first byte.

Add another 0 to the list. Compare again.

repeat another 3 times. You have your 5 bytes back.

From this we see we definitely need extra memory. Since we know such compression algorithms are impossible.